# LINQ Query without for/foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have list of values separated by commas, I need to pass those values to query and get the values from database using .net entity framework, how to write the query in LINQ without using for/foreach loop

Comment: What have you against loops? Also, it's hard to tell what exactly are you asking. Could you provide same example?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to split a string into an array; as such:

```
"1,2,3,4,5".Split(',')
```

Comment: btw; is it just me or is MSDN acting up? Everything i search returns 404 :O

Comment: seems to be working fine from my end.